# node.exe does not return output in case a package is given at the parameters

Tags: node.js, .net, less

We are using node to build the LESS files in our .NET application.
To do so, we have prepared some stuff to support that easier for all the developers. In the end we have a node version in the source control.

Everything works fine for everyone except one developer that has joined our team in the last days.
Whenever he tries to run the stuff, the CSS files are just empty.

To find the reason we have tried to skip all the stuff around and call node with the less package directly from console. This is working as expected on my PC but there is no output at the affected developers PC.
Also when we are using a path to not existing package there is no output.
On my PC there is an error logged into the console, the affected developer does not get any output.
The only parameters that seems to work are "-h" and "-v"...

As we could not find any usefull hints in the internet, maybe anyone having an idea what can be reason?
Windows-configurations, ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly we could solve the problem:

Don't ask why but uninstalling Visual Studio 2019, installing VS 2017 and installing 2019 again solved the issue somehow... everthing works as expected.

Reinstalling VS 2019 alone did not solve the problem before.

Maybe a hint in case someone else comes to this question with the same issue:
The reason for going to VS 2017 where different issues with ReSharper as well. Mainly performance issues of VS when ReSharper was active, but some functional issues too. This issues where gone as well after that.

It seems there was something broken with the VS2019 installation that was not repaired by uninstalling and reinstalling VS2019 but by VS2017...